# Missing column in JPA even if it exists

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: member_assignable_id in aguil.membership
```

I find this unusual as I simply copied the pattern from an earlier implementation (changed some names around, but still mostly the same).

The following is my setup for my entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "assignable",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"alias"}))
public abstract class Assignable {

    private Long assignableId;

    private String alias;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "assignable_id")
    public Long getAssignableId() {
        return assignableId;
    }

    public void setAssignableId(Long assignableId) {
        this.assignableId = assignableId;
    }

    @Column(name = "alias", nullable = false)
    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team extends Assignable {

    private Set<Membership> memberships;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    public Set<Membership> getMemberships() {
        return memberships;
    }

    public void setMemberships(Set<Membership> memberships) {
        this.memberships = memberships;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person",
        uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"}),
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"})
        })
public class Person extends Assignable {

    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private Set<Membership> memberships;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String firstName) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member")
    public Set<Membership> getMemberships() {
        return memberships;
    }

    public void setMemberships(Set<Membership> memberships) {
        this.memberships = memberships;
    }
}

@Entity
@IdClass(MembershipKey.class)
@Table(name = "membership")
public class Membership {

    private Long memberId;

    private Long teamId;

    private Person member;

    private Team team;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    public Long getMemberId() {
        return memberId;
    }

    public void setMemberId(Long memberId) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "team_id")
    public Long getTeamId() {
        return teamId;
    }

    public void setTeamId(Long teamId) {
        this.teamId = teamId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "assignable_id")
    public Person getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    public void setMember(Person member) {
        this.member = member;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Team.class)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "assignable_id")
    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }
}
```

The following is my sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE `aguil`.`assignable` (
  `assignable_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alias` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `pk_assignable` PRIMARY KEY (`assignable_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `uc_assignable_alias` UNIQUE (`alias`)
);

CREATE TABLE `aguil`.`person` (
  `assignable_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `pk_person` PRIMARY KEY (`assignable_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person_assignable_inheritance`
    FOREIGN KEY (`assignable_id`)
    REFERENCES `aguil`.`assignable` (`assignable_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `uc_person_username` UNIQUE (`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `uc_person_email` UNIQUE (`email`)
);

CREATE TABLE  `aguil`.`team` (
  `assignable_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `pk_team` PRIMARY KEY (`assignable_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_team_assignable_inheritance`
    FOREIGN KEY (`assignable_id`)
    REFERENCES `aguil`.`assignable` (`assignable_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `aguil`.`membership` (
  `member_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `team_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `pk_membership` PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`, `team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_membership_assignable_members`
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`)
    REFERENCES `aguil`.`person` (`assignable_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_membership_team_teams`
    FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
    REFERENCES `aguil`.`team` (`assignable_id`)
);
```

I have read some related resources in stackoverflow like: [JPA/Hibernate: "Missing Column" when joining columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882382/jpa-hibernate-missing-column-when-joining-columns) but can't still seem to fix it. I have been debugging this for hours now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forget to add the code for class Person.

Comment: Added Person. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Try adding changing Membership @ManyToOne associations to us @MapsId instead:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "assignable_id")
public Person getMember() {
    return member;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Team.class)     
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "assignable_id")
public Team getTeam() {
    return team;
}
```

Also the JOINED inheritance requires either:

- a [@DiscriminatorColumn](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/InheritanceTypeJOINED.htm)
- a [@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-inheritancetype_joined-hibernate)

You should add:

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="assignable_id")
```

to Team and Person.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue. I checked documentation and ``@MapsId`` seems to be related to Embedded Ids-- I am not sure if this is the same with ``@IdClass``

Comment: It's fine for having both an @Id column and a Join ManyToOne like in this [GitHub example of mine](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/masterclass/laboratory/concurrency/OptimisticLockingOneRootEntityMultipleVersionsTest.java). IdClass is just an ancient EJB2 style embedding id thing you shouldn't ever use it.

Comment: You need to add the sub-class referring info to the base Assignable class in Team and Person. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Still didn't work. I tried adding ``PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`` as well as a ``DiscriminatorColumn``. In addition, the other entities I copied didn't have these additional constraints for the inheritance